# Can no longer record from cassette thru sound card

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers

I used audio-recorder to record one side of one cassette. I must have clicked something because using the same setup I can no longer record.
I see this icon:

[image: Microphone to speaker]

Any idea what I did or especially how to remove it.

Not positive that is the issue but it is the only difference I see and it make sense.

Comment: Can you provide a little information so we can start to troubleshoot? For example, what version of Ubuntu were you using? They will all run different versions of their software.

Comment: Sorry. I am using  Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) with all current updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Somehow the input device got changed and when I changed it back I discovered that the volume was set to minimum.

Problem solved.